# Adjust the margins of a quote (or create a box?)

Tags: margins, tcolorbox, quotation

How do I adjust the left and right margins by 2cm, a top margin of 1.5cm and a bottom margin of 2cm? Is it possible to do less complicated by creating a box?

Here is my code...

```
\newenvironment{ex}[2]{\begin{quote}{\color{blue}Lorem #1.} \itshape{#2}}{\end{quote}}
...
\section{Lorem ipsum}
Some text

\begin{ex}{ipsum}
Some text
\end{ex}

\section{Lorem ipsum}
Some text
```

[image]

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `quoting`. There should be just *one* argument (the title).

You can see that no blank line after `\end{ex}` results in no indent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newenvironment{ex}[1]
 {%
  \quoting[leftmargin=2cm,rightmargin=2cm]%
  \noindent\textcolor{blue!75}{#1.} \itshape\ignorespaces
 }
 {\endquoting}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{ex}{Blue title}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{ex}
\lipsum[3][1-4]

\begin{ex}{Blue title}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{ex}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: mwe]

A simple centered minipage of the right width with two vertical spaces inside can do that. Note that external glues can change a lot the apparent top and bottom margins of the quote, so pay attention to blank lines before and after the minipage.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum,geometry}
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{Lorem ipsum} 
    \lipsum[1][1-6]\par
    {\centering
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-4cm}
    \vspace{1.5cm} \lipsum[2][1-9] \vspace{2cm}
    \end{minipage}\par}
    \lipsum[3][1-9]
        
    \end{document}
```

As quotes are really a special list, you can also make your custom list. An inconvenient is that you want different top and bottom spaces, but lists use `\topsep +\parkip` in both cases, but you can set this to 1.5 cm and simply add 0.5cm after the list.

[image: mwe2]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum,geometry,xcolor}
    
    \newenvironment{myquote}
    {\begin{list}{}%
    % before
    {\setlength\topsep{\dimexpr1.5cm-\parskip-\partopsep}
    \setlength\listparindent{0cm}
    \setlength\labelwidth{0cm}
    \setlength\itemindent{0em}
    \setlength\parsep{\baselineskip}
    \setlength\leftmargin{2cm}
    \setlength\rightmargin{2cm}
    \setlength\labelsep{2cm}
    }\item \color{blue}\em\parindent1em }
    % after
    {\end{list}\vspace{0.5cm}}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{Lorem ipsum} 
    \lipsum[1][1-8]\par \lipsum[2][1-8]
    
    \begin{myquote}
        \lipsum[3][1-8]\par \lipsum[4][1-8]
    \end{myquote}
    
    \lipsum[5][1-8]\par \lipsum[6][1-8]
    
    \end{document}
```